# Passengers ticket check combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

$500$ passengers are about to pass from $10$ ticket control stations. Every passenger must pass from just one ticket station.

How many control senarios could take place, if every station facilitates at least $20$ passengers?

(Alternatively: How many ways are there for the control to take place, if every station facilitates at least $20$ passengers?)

*Keep in mind that the stations are distinct entities while the passengers are not.*

What I have done so far is take out the $20*10=200$ (non-distinct) passangers that are for sure going to pass from whatever station. Now we have to determine the number of ways that the rest passengers could pass. **That is, we should find all the combinations of passengers being placed in $10$ different stations**.

Comment: This is a standard [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  To get it in standard form, assume that  $20+n_i$ passengers pass through station $i$, with $n_i≥0$.

Comment: @lulu Can't really identify the relation there. Could you give any extra help? Thanks!

Comment: @ lulu: I was originally thinking of stars and bars, but I hesitated to provide this answer because the  "balls" (people) in this case are distinguishable, not indistinguishable.

Comment: @MatthewHolder  The problem states "Keep in mind that the stations are discrete entities while the passengers are not." which I took to mean that the people are indistinguishable.  That is, two arrangements are the same iff the same number of people pass through the $i^{th}$ station for each $i$.  Anyway, that's how I read it.

Comment: @johngonidelis  If the passengers are indistinguishable, then this is literally Stars and Bars.  Since we have taken out $200$ at the start, you just need to count the $10-$tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $500-200=300$.  If the passengers were meant to be distinct, then you should clarify your post.

Comment: @lulu The passengers are **indistinguishable**

Comment: That's what I assumed, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @lulu Does that mean that the solution is $C(10+300-1, 300)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, although still I cannot understand the rational behind that.

Comment: Maybe they meant to write "distinct" instead of "discrete."

Comment: @MatthewHolder Thanks! fixed ;)

Comment: @johngonidelis  Do you agree that the arrangements are determined by the $10-$tuples $\{n_i\}_{i=1}^{10}$?

Comment: @lulu Yeah sure!

Comment: And do you believe that $\sum n_i=300$?

Comment: @lulu ok yeah...

Comment: So, then, the problem is to count the $10-$tuples of non-negative integers which sum to $300$.  That is what the Stars and Bars method is for.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean *non-negative integers* ?

Comment: The $n_i$ are integers, clearly, since $n_i$ counts a group of passengers.   The $n_i$ are non-negative because you assumed that at least $20$ passengers go through gate $i$.  Since $20+n_i$ passengers go through gate $i$, we must have $n_i≥0$.

Comment: As an exercise:  you could have used the other Stars and Bars formula, the one for strictly positive solutions.  For that one we define $m_i$ by saying that exactly  $19+m_i$ passengers go through gate $i$.  Then $m_i>0$.  Now we get $\sum m_i=500-19\times 10=310$.  Of course, the eventual answer ought to coincide with what you got before.